# Compute $\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{F(x,t)-f(x)}{t}$ where $F(x,t)$ is a complicated integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Consider a function $F(x,t)$ defined by $$F(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (1-e^{-2t})}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{|y-xe^{-t}|^{2}}{2(1-e^{-2t})}\right)f(y)\,dy.$$ Then I want to compute the limit $$\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{F(x,t)-f(x)}{t}.$$

It is undecided and actually part of the question what property of $f(x)$ should have, so that the above limit converges uniformly (or at least pointwise).

For now, I guess $f(y)$ should at last be uniformly continuous on a compact support, perhaps it should be $2-$times continuously differentiable, but I am not sure.

Then, I try to compute the limit, but it turned out that I don't really know how to start. We can definitely analyze the thing without taking the limit: $$\frac{F(x,t)-f(x)}{t}=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi (1-e^{-2t})}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{|y-xe^{-t}|^{2}}{2(1-e^{-2t})}\right)f(y)\,dy-\frac{f(x)}{t}.$$

Since we have really complicated things in the integral, my expectation is that the first term just converges to $0$ uniformly.

By the assumption that $f(y)$ is bounded uniformly continuous, we can bound the integral with sup norm, $$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{|y-xe^{-t}|^{2}}{2(1-e^{-2t})}\right)f(y)\,dy\right|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\exp\left(-\frac{|y-xe^{-t}|^{2}}{2(1-e^{-2t})}\right)\right|dy,$$ but then I don't know how to proceed...

Is there anyway to compute such a limit? Thank you!

Comment: I agree with your guess that $f(y)$ should be at least twice differentiable. Could you give us some more context about this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a suggestion.

The function 
\begin{aligned}
u(x;t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-\frac{|y-x|^2}{2t}}f(y)\,dy=W_t*f(x)
\end{aligned}
where $W_t(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}$ is solution to the heat equation problem with initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$

\begin{aligned}
\partial_t u&=\frac12\partial^2_{xx}u\\
u(x,0)&=f(x)
\end{aligned}

$f$ in principle can be in $L_1$. Assuming continuity also gives $u(x,t)\rightarrow f(x)$ as $t\rightarrow0$.

What you have is 
$$F(x,t)=u(xe^{-t},1- e^{-2t})$$

So twice differentiable might be a reasonable extra assumption. The problem can also be posed in terms of the generator of Brwonian motion, which gives you the heat equation.

As $F(x,0)=u(x,0)=f(x)$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(x,t)-f(x)}{t}&=(\partial_tF)(x,t)|_{t=0}\\
&= (\partial_xu(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t}),\partial_tu(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t}))\cdot(-xe^{-t},2e^{-2t})|_{t=0}\\
&=-x\partial_xu(x,0)+2\partial_tu(x,0)=-xf'(x)+f''(x)
\end{aligned}under the assumption that $f$ is twice differentiable in $L_1$, e.g., if $f$ is a Schwartz function.

Comment: so in your notation, $$\lim_{t\searrow 0}\dfrac{u(x,t)-u(x)}{t}$$ is the infinitesimal generator of a brownian motion? what should I do to involve the $u(xe^{-t},\sqrt{1-e^{-2t}})$?

Comment: It should be $(1-e^{-2t})$. In any event, $F(x,t)$ of the problem is $u(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t})$, where $u$ is solution to the Cauchy problem above.

Comment: I got this, but then how do I compute my limit? I understand $F(x,t)=u(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t})$, so that $$\lim_{t\searrow 0}\dfrac{F(x,t)-f(x)}{t}=\lim_{t\searrow 0}\dfrac{u(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t})-f(x)}{t}.....$$ I still don't know how to compute it...

Comment: Use the chain rule. The limit you are looking for is $\partial_tF$ at $t=0$. Notice that $u(x,0)=f(x)$.

Comment: $F(x,0)=u(x,0)=f(x)$

Comment: I got it, so $\partial_{t}F=\partial_{t} u(xe^{-t},1-e^{-2t})=u_{t}(xe^{-t}, 1-e^{-2t})\cdot 2e^{-2t}$, so at $t=0$, we have the limit is $2u_{t}(x,0)|_{t=0}$?  but what is this thing? I am really sorry for these many confusions...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107161/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-jacobsonradical).